# Fields “Website”, “Store” and “Store view” are set to null in newsletter after checkout

Tags: checkout, newsletter

Does anybody know why, when a customer process an order, the field "store_id" on "newsletter_subscriber" mysql table is reset to "0". This cause me problem when I want to send newsletter to a specific store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my problem. It's because the customers was associated with "store_id" 0 in "customer_entity" Mysql table.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? Is there a way to set that "store_id" to something else for all customers?